# Troubleshoot DynamoDB to Elastic Search

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Let's suppose I have a database on DynamoDB, and I am currently using streams and lambda functions to send that data to Elasticsearch.

Here's the thing, supposing the data is saved successfully on DynamoDB, is there a way for me to be 100% sure that the data has been saved on Elasticsearch as well?

Considering I have a function to save that data on DDB is there a way for me communicate with the lambda function triggered by DDB before returning a status code answer, so I can receive confirmation before returning?

I want to do that in order to return ok both from my function and the lambda function at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like the correct approach for this problem. We generally use DynamoDB Streams + Lambda for operations that are async in nature and when we don't have to communicate the status of this Lambda execution to the client.

So I suggest the following two approaches that are the closest to what you are trying to achieve -

1. Make the operation completely synchronous. i.e., do the DynamoDB insert and ElasticSearch insert in the same call (without any Ddb Stream and Lambda triggers). This will ensure that you return the correct status of both writes to the client. Also, in case the ES insert fails, you have an option to revert the Ddb write and then return the complete status as failed.
2. The first approach obviously adds to the Latency of the function. So you can continue with your original approach, but let the client know about it. It will work as follows -

- Client calls your API.
- API inserts record into Ddb and returns to the client.
- The client receives the status and displays a message to the user that their request is being processed.
- The client then starts polling for the status of the ES insert via another API.
- Meanwhile, the Ddb stream triggers the ES insert Lambda fn and completes the ES write.
- The poller on the client comes to know about the successful insert into ES and displays a final success message to the user.